# JSON <>fixed width file transformations in Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I am looking for a recommendation on how to best implement the following two use case in Nifi.

1. A) Pick up fixed width flat file from SFTP, B) read line-by-line, C) transformed into a JSON payload, and  D) used as a request body in a POST to a REST API
2. A) Fetch JSON payload from a REST API, B) transformed into a fixed width flat file, and C) put onto an SFTP server

For Use Case #1, 1A, 1B and 1D are simple.  To achieve 1C, I took this approach:

1. Created new attribute using UpdateAttribute called `payload` from the content (e.g. the current line from the flat file)
2. Created 2 attributes `accountData` and `userData`, parsing `payload` attribute using `substring()` and `trim()`, as shown

[image]

Then, it is easy to call InvokeHTTP to do what is required in 1D.

For Use Case #2, 2A and 2C are simple.  To achieve 2B, I took this approach:

1. Used ConvertRecord from JSONTreeReader to FreeFormTextRecordSetWriter, configuring the `text` of the FreeFormTextRecordSetWriter as shown.

[image]

I'm seeking help on thoughts for a better implementation of 1C and 2B as I'm a bit new to Nifi.  Thanks.

Both of these solutions work, but they are very supportable.  If there are multiple fixed width file formats (which there are/will be), it requires a lot of configuration/code embedded into the attributes.  My assumption is I could write a custom record processor, but I'm hoping someone might provide a better means?  JoltTransformRecord?  Anything?

Comment: Good work mate, would be great if you could also add to the question how you are currently parsing the Fixed Width file. `ConvertRecord` could help in this conversion you saw any issues there.

Comment: @datawrangler thanks for your comment.  The first screen shot shows how I'm parsing the inbound fixed width file.  As you can see, it requires coding the file format via substring calls into the new attributes, which will be difficult to maintain long term.   I'm not sure how I could use ConvertRecord in that situation.